# Python Sorting tuple by integer

Tags: python

I am constructing a highscore table in python. 
It is a tuple with every input being a name + score.

example:

```
Highscore = [(1000,"Carl"), (945,"Eric"), (883,"Beta"), (823,"Alpha")]
```

When someone gets a better score i want to add their score and name:

```
Highscore = [(1000,"Carl"), (945,"Eric"), (883,"Beta"), (823,"Alpha"),(NEWSCORE),(NEWNAME)]
```

Then sort it to so the highest score is in the top. This is where the error occurs and the output is not by sorted by highest score...

I´ve tried `Highscore.sort(reverse=True)` and `sorted(Highscore,key=lambda tup: tup[1])`

`Highscore.sort` sorts by alphabetical order and sorted gives me the following error: `TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < list()`

Comment: `sorted(Highscore, reverse=True, key=lambda tup: tup[0])` works for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're adding a _tuple_ and not a _list_?

Comment: Don't you want `(NEWSCORE, NEWNAME)` rather than `(NEWSCORE), (NEWNAME)`?

Comment: Also, `Highscore = [(1000,"Carl"), (945,"Eric"), (883,"Beta"), (823,"Alpha"),(NEWSCORE),(NEWNAME)]` is definitely not what you're looking for; `Highscore = [(1000,"Carl"), (945,"Eric"), (883,"Beta"), (823,"Alpha"),(NEWSCORE, NEWNAME)]` would be closer. Can you add debug print before and after adding the new score? Before sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not add an tuple to your highscore list, but a list. Try to add a tuple to `Highscore` and sort then:

```
Highscore = [(1000,"Carl"), (945,"Eric"), (883,"Beta"), (823,"Alpha")]
Highscore.append((score, name))
Highscore.sort(reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you need to add the new value as a single tuple.

What you have:

```
Highscore.append((NEWSCORE),(NEWNAME))
```

What you should have:

```
Highscore.append((NEWSCORE, NEWNAME))
```

If you do this, `Highscore.sort(reverse=True)` should do the trick.